# On Click of $this check checkbox

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am setting up a filtering system that will filter search results based on the filter selected.
The objective is to have the entire container clickable rather than just a label.

//html

```
<div class="Container">
<input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
<div class="lbl">1</div>
</div>
<div class="Container">
<input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
<div class="lbl">2</div>
</div>
<div class="Container">
<input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
<div class="lbl">3</div>
</div>
```

//jquery (I've included a couple of different options that I've tried).  Ultimately, when a user clicks on one of the containers, I'd like the input within that specific container to be checked.

```
 $('.Container').on('click', function(){
    
            $(this).closest('div').find('input').click();
        $(this).find('input').click();
        $(this).find('input[data-type="prodType"]').click();
    
    });
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Remove all other codes only keep `$(this).find('input').click();` inside your handler see if that works .

Comment: @swati none of the examples I included in the code above worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a combination of raising multiple click events on the input, which cancel each other out by toggling the `input` on/off, and also event propagation where the event is trapped multiple times, and the input is again toggled multiple times.

To address this you can ensure that the element which fired the event was *not* the `input`, and toggle the `checked` state appropriately. Note the use of `closest()` here to get the `.Container` element, as the event can fire on the child `.lbl` element, or the `.Container` itself.

```js
$('.Container').on('click', e => {
  let $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.is('input'))
    return;

  $target.closest('.Container').find('input').prop('checked', (i, c) => !c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
  <div class="lbl">1</div>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
  <div class="lbl">2</div>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
  <div class="lbl">3</div>
</div>
```

That being said, this approach is not ideal. You can achieve it just as easily by using plain HTML with no JS at all - use the `label` element. If the reason you're attempting to achieve your goal in the manner above is for styling reasons then the `label` element can easily be styled using CSS to match you needs. Try this:

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<label class="Container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
  <span class="lbl">1</span>
</label>
<label class="Container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
  <span class="lbl">2</span>
</label>
<label class="Container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputBx" data-type="prodType">
  <span class="lbl">3</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.Container').on('click', function(){ 
            $(this).closest('div').find('input').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).find('input[data-type="prodType"]').prop('checked', true);
    
    });
```